# Imaged returned as base64 encoded string when scraping news article

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, base64

I am new to scraping data and I am trying to extract the following image from a news article:

```
<img alt="Preparing for the NBA's Victor Wembanyama revolution" class="" data-mptype="image" src="https://a.espncdn.com/photo/2023/0218/r1133272_1296x518_5-2.jpg">
```

Here the image tag seems to show up as a real link to a photo which I can see on my browser. However, when I try to extract this data using BeautifulSoup I am returned a base64 encoded string:

> ("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7)"

I have not been able to figure out how to do anything with this string as I can't display it on my web page like I want to.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the script I have wrote to extract the data from the web page.

```py
def scrape_news(request):
    team = request.GET.get('team')
    hide_names = request.GET.get('hide_names') == 'true'


    # Set the URL of the ESPN.com page that contains the team's news
    url = f'https://www.espn.com/nba/team/_/name/{team}'

    # Send a GET request to the URL and parse the response with BeautifulSoup
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    # Find all the news articles on the page
    news_articles = soup.find_all('article', {'class': 'contentItem'})

    # Create a list to store the news articles
    articles_list = []

    # Loop through each news article and extract the relevant information
    for article in news_articles:
        team_heading = soup.find('title').text.split('-')[0].strip()

        latest_article = article.find('a', class_='contentItem__content')
        
        # Check if latest_article is not None
        if latest_article is not None:
            headline = latest_article.find('h2', class_='contentItem__title').text.strip()
            link = latest_article['href']
            img = latest_article['src']

            # check image
            print(img) # prints encoded string


            # Create a dictionary for the current article
            article_dict = {
                'team_heading': team_heading,
                'headline': headline,
                'link': link,
                'hide_names': hide_names
            }

            # Add the article dictionary to the list
            articles_list.append(article_dict)

    # Render the template with the news articles
    return render(request, 'scrape_news.html', {'articles_list': articles_list})
```

Comment: That base64 image looks like it is a placeholder/default that gets updated via javascript

Comment: Do you mean you want to put the base64 image into your `scrape_news.html` template? If so, you can add an `<img>` element with that base64 string as its `src`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, those are placeholders that are to be updated by JavaScript. Fortunately, the data you want seems to be available [inside a `script` tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxblz.png) in the source HTML. You can slice out the `window['__espnfitt__']` object from the script and then parse it as [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) before extracting the details you want.

```py
import requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#################################################
# for printing and returning in one statement ###
def vRet(toPrint, toRet=[]):                   ##
    print(toPrint)                             ##
    return toRet                               ##
                                               ##
## extract a nested value with a list of keys ###
def valgetter(obj, *keys, defaultVal=None):    ##
    try:                                       ##
        for k in keys: obj = obj[k]            ##
    except: return defaultVal                  ##
    return obj                                ###
#################################################


def get_team_stories(team_endpt):
    teamUrl = f'https://www.espn.com/nba/team/_/name/{team_endpt}'
    resp = requests.get(teamUrl)
    rMsg = f'[Received <{resp.status_code} {resp.reason}> from {resp.url}]\n'
    if not resp.ok: return vRet(f'{rMsg}! Failed to scrape {teamUrl}')

    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'html.parser')
    try:
        pgData = json.loads(soup.find(
            'script', string=lambda s: s and ''.join(
                s.split()).startswith("window['__espnfitt__']=")
        ).text.split('=', 1)[-1].strip().strip(';'))['page']

        team_heading = pgData['meta']['title'].split('-')[0].strip()
        clubhouseCols = pgData['content']['clubhouse']['columns']
        articles = clubhouseCols['middleColumn']['clubhouse']['feed']
    except Exception as e: return vRet(repr(e))

    if not isinstance(articles, list): 
        return vRet(f'{rMsg}Expected list of articles, not {type(articles)}')
    if not articles: return vRet(f'{rMsg}No articles for {team_endpt}')

    def formLink(l):
        if not isinstance(l, str): return l 
        if l.startswith('/espn/'): 
            return l.replace('/espn/', 'https://www.espn.com/', 1)
        if l.startswith('/'): return f'https://www.espn.com{l}'
        return l

    rData = [{
        'team_heading': team_heading, 'headline': a['headline'], 
        'link': formLink(a['link']), 'img_url': valgetter(a,'image','url')
    } for a in articles if isinstance(a, dict) and 'headline' in a]
    if len(rData) != len(articles): 
        print(f'! Could only extract {len(rData)} of {len(articles)} articles')
    return rData
```

---

I tested the function above with

```py
team_endpoints = ['bos/boston-celtics', 'phi/philadelphia-76ers', 
                  'bkn/brooklyn-nets', 'ny/new-york-knicks']
team_stories = []
for te in team_endpoints: team_stories += get_team_stories(te)

print(len(team_stories), 'articles collected\n')
```

[image: opdf]

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply use espn's api. You can just pull all the headlines for NBA:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/basketball/nba/news?team=1'
jsonData = requests.get(url).json()

articles = jsonData['articles']
teamIds = pd.json_normalize(articles,
                       record_path=['categories'])
teamIds = teamIds[(teamIds['teamId'].notnull()) & (teamIds['sportId'] == 46)][['description', 'teamId']].drop_duplicates()

dfs = []
for idx, row in teamIds.iterrows():
    team = row['description']
    teamId = int(row['teamId'])
    print(team)
    url = f'https://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/basketball/nba/news?team={teamId}'
    jsonData = requests.get(url).json()

    articles = jsonData['articles']
    df = pd.json_normalize(articles,
                           record_path=['images'])
    dfs.append(df)

final_df = pd.concat(dfs).drop_duplicates()
```

**Output:**

```
print(final_df.head(10).to_string())
                                                                                       name  width          id                                            credit    type                                                                                                                                                                 url  height dataSourceIdentifier                                  alt                                                                                                                                                       caption
0                                                                  NBA logo court [600x400]    600  32293398.0                                  Associated Press  header                                                                                                       https://a.espncdn.com/photo/2021/0927/r915150_600x400_3-2.jpg     400                  NaN                                  NaN                                                                                                                                                           NaN
1                                            NBA post-free agency power rankings [1296x729]   1296  38031584.0                              Illustration by ESPN  header                                                                                                   https://a.espncdn.com/photo/2023/0718/nba_power_rankings_16x9.jpg     729        f5e4098bd673e  NBA post-free agency power rankings                                                                                                                                                              
2                            Perk on Jaylen Brown's supermax: One championship isn't enough    576         NaN                                               NaN   Media  https://a.espncdn.com/media/motion/2023/0725/dm_230725_dm_230725_NBA_Perk_on_Jaylen_Brown_rev_pub2tag/dm_230725_dm_230725_NBA_Perk_on_Jaylen_Brown_rev_pub2tag.jpg     324                  NaN                                  NaN               Kendrick Perkins and Chiney Ogwumike discuss the expectations on Jaylen Brown following his five-year, $304 million extension with the Celtics.
3                                                                   Isaiah Mobley [576x324]    576  38022455.0       Photo by Jeff Bottari/NBAE via Getty Images  header                                                                                                     https://a.espncdn.com/photo/2023/0717/r1198755_576x324_16-9.jpg     324        f834b42626edc                                  NaN                            Isaiah Mobley and the Cleveland Cavaliers will face the Houston Rockets in the NBA 2K24 Summer League championship game on Monday.
4                                                     Chet Holmgren summer league [576x324]    576  37963701.0  Photo by Melissa Majchrzak/NBAE via Getty Images  header                                                                                                     https://a.espncdn.com/photo/2023/0705/r1194328_576x324_16-9.jpg     324        b7351111f9cd6                                  NaN  Chet Holmgren scored 15 points and grabbed nine rebounds in the Oklahoma City Thunder's 95-85 win against the Utah Jazz in the Salt Lake City summer league.
5  Brandon Miller #24 of the Charlotte Hornets defends against Victor Wembanyama  [608x342]    608  37987258.0                         Candice Ward/Getty Images  header                                                                                                     https://a.espncdn.com/photo/2023/0710/r1196026_608x342_16-9.jpg     342        f53c0bfd44d38                                  NaN                                              Victor Wembanyama and Brandon Miller played against each other on the first night of the NBA 2K24 Summer League.
6                                                     Chet Holmgren summer league [576x324]    576  37990534.0               Photo by Chris Gardner/Getty Images  header                                                                                                     https://a.espncdn.com/photo/2023/0710/r1196239_576x324_16-9.jpg     324        e773f8ec23d7c                                  NaN                                      Oklahoma City Thunder forward Chet Holmgren now weighs 208 pounds and appears more physical in his second summer league.
7                                                                   Chet Holmgren [608x342]    608  37980950.0                Photo by Candice Ward/Getty Images  header                                                                                                     https://a.espncdn.com/photo/2023/0708/r1195586_608x342_16-9.jpg     342        288a5fc222b16                                  NaN                                                                                                                                                           NaN
8                                                                  Keyonte George [576x324]    576  38014766.0                Photo by Candice Ward/Getty Images  header                                                                                                     https://a.espncdn.com/photo/2023/0715/r1198090_576x324_16-9.jpg     324        779a8f833ef77                                  NaN                                                                            Keyonte George was one of the best rookies at NBA 2K24 Summer League in Las Vegas.
9                                                  Cavs win 2023 summer league championship    576         NaN                                               NaN   Media                                                https://a.espncdn.com/media/motion/2023/0717/ss_20230717_225120331_23036861384/ss_20230717_225120331_23036861384.jpg     324                  NaN                                  NaN                                                        The Cavaliers celebrate winning the 2023 summer league championship after defeating the Rockets 99-78.
```